# Props missing after passing to children when using draft-js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm kinda new to react and thought that in the constructor function, using `super(props)` can fully receive the props that passed by parents. But however, I can't get the string `test` from my parent component.

So in the parent component, I pass the string "test" as props

```js
import React from 'react';
import Post from '../components/post';
import "../components/css/post.css"
class Bulletin extends React.Component  {
  render()
  {
      console.log(this.props);
      return (
       <div>
           <Post test={"sent from parent"}/>
       </div>
      );
  }
}

export default Bulletin;
```

And then in `Post.js`, I print the props in two places:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Edit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="editor" onClick={this.focus}>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The two outputs are both `{className: "editor"}` which is not what I need. I need the string `{test: "sent from parent"}` and don't know why this doesn't works for me.

Comment: Could you post how `Post` component is propagating its props? Maybe it's not sending them down to `Edit` component.

Comment: I dont know why is its not working. May be you are implementing wrong way. Here is  live demo link. Its working fine : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-58gxzh

Comment: @mersocarlin God, I made an obvious mistake. Turn out that I forget there is a component `Post` between `Edit` and `Bulletin`, thus nothing is passed to `Edit`.

Comment: After that, the code is working now.